# Python3.4 installation erroring out on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: python, macos, python-3.4, macos-big-sur

After installing python 3.4.3 and on running the command python3.4, it gives an error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
  Reason: image not found
```

Comment: See comment at https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOSBeta/comments/hfknpa/is_corefoundation_missing_for_everyone_on_big_sur/

Comment: Why do you need Python 3.4? It's not supported anymore (and neither is 3.5).

Comment: I know, but the production env uses 3.4, so I also have to simulate the same env.

Comment: How did you install Python 3.4?  I know there are a number of ways of doing so.  I'll just say that I install all of my Python versions (I have 4 on my Mac right now) with "homebrew", and I've never run into any problems like this.  I therefore recommend that if you aren't already doing so, you uninstall and try reinstalling Python with "homebrew". - just my $.02.

Comment: I installed python from the default pkg installer available at https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-343/. Can you share the home brew command to install Python 3.4.3? P.S. I also tried pyenv, did not work.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to the above problem. It can be done using pyenv manager installed using brew instead of using default pkg installer.

You might face few errors in that too like:
`implicit declaration of function 'getentropy' is invalid in C99`

Those errors can be avoided by using a patch.
[Patch link](https://gist.github.com/orip/00142a498cf6d0c536b5d38771ad6249)

Following this entire link should help you in getting Python 3.4.x running in BigSur.

Answer (score 0):

(2022 update) The patch isn't enough, as explained later in the [thread](https://gist.github.com/orip/00142a498cf6d0c536b5d38771ad6249?permalink_comment_id=3958640#gistcomment-3958640). Instead:

1. Save [the updated patch](https://gist.github.com/orip/00142a498cf6d0c536b5d38771ad6249?permalink_comment_id=3617160#gistcomment-3617160) locally.
2. Run the following 2 commands:

> brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies --force openssl
>
> brew reinstall zlib

3. Replace *Python-3.4.3-macos.patch* with the path to your saved patch, and run:

> ```
> CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include -I$(brew --prefix readline)/include" LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix readline)/lib
> -L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib" pyenv install 3.4.3 --patch < Python-3.4.3-macos.patch
> ```